# How can i change two items while only hovering over one

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this problem and I can't find anything about it
The problem is that I want to make my image brighter when I hover over the card
How can I do this??

**My example**

```
.card-img {
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 340px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 16px 30px -14px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 30px -14px #000000;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
  background: #222329;

  .card-img{
    filter: brightness(1000%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the css image filters, like this:

```css
img:hover {-webkit-filter: brightness(150%); }
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing the Kickstarter logo on a blue background.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62bCB/)

or you can use simply:

```css
img { 
  opacity: 0.7; 
} 

img:hover { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Image tag is inside the card tag you can use the `>` selector:

```
.card-img {
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 340px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 16px 30px -14px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 30px -14px #000000;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
  background: #222329;

  
}
.card:hover > .card-img { /* select every card-image inside an hover card */
    filter: brightness(1000%);
}
```